# JSZip generateAsync times out when run in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, jszip

Very strange issue when I try to upgrade `jest` from v26 to v29.

A test executes

```
    console.log("before fzip", JSZip.support.blob);
    const fzip = await zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });
    console.log("fzip", fzip);
```

1. If I run `jest` v26.6.x, it succeeds as long as I have `jest-environment-jsdom` v26.5.x in `package.json'
2. If I remove `jest-environment-jsdom`, the call fails (goes to `catch`):

```
 error! TypeError: this._timerAPIs.setImmediate is not a function
          at FakeTimers._fakeSetImmediate
```

3. If I upgrade `jest` and `jest-environment-jsdom` to v29.0.x, the call times out. I can see the first log message but not the second.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is interested.

Apparently, `JSZip.generateAsync` calls `setImmediate` internally, so the following works:

```
import {setImmediate} from “timers”
…
global.setImmediate = setImmediate
```

(`jest` v27 was failing as it had an issue with `setImmediate`)